# Newsfeed webpart not working properly when using AAM, need advice/help

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping, newsfeed

I have a webbapplication with two urls in the AAM default zone like this:

[image]

Binding in the webbapp for https://url2.domain.com is done as well.

I also tried the below setup but the behaviour is the same:

[image]

The reason for this is that we would like to access the site from two different URL's.

Navigating the site and subsites is no problem with url1 or url2 and all content is there as far as I can determin.

The problem on the is that everytime you try to post something in the sitefeed webpart to the root site or any subsites or try to reply/like when navigating through url2 it throws this error:

> Looks like the newsfeed was removed from the site, the site was
>   deleted, or there's some temporary network problem. You can try again
>   later or stop following the site from the sites page.

If I navigate to https://url2.domain.com/newsfeed.aspx I can make posts and comments just fine so it seems like it is only the webpart that is not working.

I've tried my best to read and determin the error from the ULS log but to no avail so I'm here asking if someone has encountered this problem in the past or maybe can just point me in the right direction?

[ULS Log entries here, sorry about the formating](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ftgqbd84odsm28s/NewsFeedErrorULS.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you please confirm if this behavior is uniform for all users or just one?

Comment: The behaviour is consistent for all users no matter what rights level.

Comment: Are you able to find the solution ?

Comment: Sorry but we never solved it before I left the project